# Change width of detail UILabel - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can you change the width of the detail UILabel on a left detail UITableView cell without subclassing it? In other words, the text in the left label is too long, and I want to move the center of the two labels to the right.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for these edits like this one?

Comment: Nothing other than improving grammar. I can stop doing them if they violate any anti-bumping policy that I was not aware of.

Comment: You should generally only edit when there's a notable improvement you can make. He edit here didn't seem to meet that test. But especially editing numerous posts, and especially older posts, on top of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the frame in the `-layoutSubviews` method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];
self.detailTextLabel.frame = //yourFrame
}
```

Comment: In other words, there is no way to do it without subclassing UITableViewCell?

Comment: i'm afraid not. Sorry, i didnt notice this earlier